# What is the best mindmapper for emacs?

Tags: emacs, mind-mapping

I have tried to use [Org Mode](http://orgmode.org/) via [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to organise information, but somehow I miss information that was easy to see with mind mapping software.

Is there anything that can visually display information, in much the same way as Freemind?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly answer your question. But [org-brain](https://github.com/Kungsgeten/org-brain) is worth a try.

It is concept map tools for Emacs inspired form [The Brain](http://thebrain.com/)

Comment: This is actually great!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Export your org files to [freemind](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FreeMind) when you want to review.

Comment: Can you provide some steps on how to achieve this? The link is of no help for a novice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [org2opml](https://github.com/semk/Org2OPML) to convert to OPML, which can be opened with MindNode, Mindmeister, and many other mindmapping apps. You can also copy-paste plain-text lists directly into MindNode and it will parse the indentation correctly.